# Using intersphinx for internal documentation

Tags: python-sphinx

I would like to use intersphinx for internal documentation to crosslink between various pieces of internal services and internal documentation.

However, they are not on a secure internal network.

Is there a way to point intersphinx to `objects.inv` that is behind authentication?

Which authentication schemes are supported?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's a way to pull `objects.inv` through authentication, but one alternative solution is to download the `objects.inv` file(s) you need to a location you can access without authentication, and then specify this local copy of the file(s) in the `intersphinx_mapping` parameter in `conf.py`:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {'keyname', ('uri/to/doc/repo/root', 'uri/to/local/objects.inv')}
```

While you'd have to re-pull the file periodically to ensure it's up to date, for the time being perhaps it's better than nothing?

Comment: Yup, that's what I've ended up with, but would still love to be able to use direct approach on less complex projects.